# Makefile : Automatically compile all c files, keeping .o files in separate folder

Tags: c, makefile, gnu-make

What I have is a directory with 3 sub-directories. src/ for .c and .h files, bin/ where the compiled executable is supposed to go and obj/ where I want the .obj files to go.

Now I want the makefile to compile every .c file from src (without me having to list them all in the makefile) and put the .o files in obj and the executable built from foo.c saved as bin/foo.

Can someone help me out? Whenever I use wildcards, make complains about rules not being there and when I use implicit rules, it doesn't put the object files in a separate folder.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

To build `foo.o` from `foo.c`, locally:

```makefile
foo.o: foo.c
    $(CC) -c $< -o $@
```

To do the same, but with any needed header files in `src/`:

```makefile
SRC := src

foo.o: foo.c
    $(CC) -I$(SRC) -c $< -o $@
```

To do the same, but with the source file in `src/`:

```makefile
SRC := src

foo.o: $(SRC)/foo.c
    $(CC) -I$(SRC) -c $< -o $@
```

To do that, but put the object file in `obj/`:

```makefile
SRC := src
OBJ := obj

$(OBJ)/foo.o: $(SRC)/foo.c
    $(CC) -I$(SRC) -c $< -o $@
```

A pattern rule that will do that for any such object file (`obj/foo.o`, `obj/bar.o`, ...):

```makefile
SRC := src
OBJ := obj

$(OBJ)/%.o: $(SRC)/%.c
    $(CC) -I$(SRC) -c $< -o $@
```

To create the list of desired objects:

```makefile
SOURCES := $(wildcard $(SRC)/*.c)
OBJECTS := $(patsubst $(SRC)/%.c, $(OBJ)/%.o, $(SOURCES))
```

And a rule to cover them all:

```makefile
all: $(OBJECTS)
```

**Putting it all together:**

```makefile
SRC := src
OBJ := obj

SOURCES := $(wildcard $(SRC)/*.c)
OBJECTS := $(patsubst $(SRC)/%.c, $(OBJ)/%.o, $(SOURCES))

all: $(OBJECTS)
    $(CC) $^ -o $@

$(OBJ)/%.o: $(SRC)/%.c
    $(CC) -I$(SRC) -c $< -o $@
```

**Note that this has one big shortcoming:** is does not track dependencies on header files. This can be done automatically, but it's a subtle trick; it can wait until you've mastered this much.

Comment: Thank you for the fantastic answer. The last snippet won't actually build the executable, but adding that was no problem and all the files are where I want them to be :)

Comment: That last pattern rule would probably look better as a static pattern rule methinks.

Comment: @bobbogo: I agree, but I was trying for simplicity.

Comment: where can i get the "subtle trick" ... i'm ready for more, master

Comment: @activedecay: look at [Mad Scientist's excellent paper](http://make.mad-scientist.net/papers/advanced-auto-dependency-generation/). And please learn to use punctuation and upper-case letters.

Comment: @Beta where can i get the "subtle trick" ... i'm ready for more, master ?!